# Access VBA not working to find entries in database between a date range

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

### Background

I have a form that have multiple button on the page. Each button is used to create a html report so that the data can be easily emailed to other people. I have managed to get 2 button working fine and am about 90% the way to getting the other 2 works as they use the same code, just pass different variables in to the sub.

### Problem

One of the buttons is to select all records from the "Questions" table where the "CheckDate" field is between 2 dates selected on the form. This is where I am falling down and don't seem to be able to get any search results at all. I have tried using plain text as a search string so that I know the statement is correct but this also doesn't work.

### Data

Table = Questions

Fields (Type):

- ID (AutoNumber)
- NameID (Number)
- CheckDate (Date/Time)
- Problem (Number)
- LogScreen (Yes/No)
- ActionPlan (Yes/No)
- Owner (Yes/No)
- DueDate (Yes/No)
- LatestStatus (Yes/No)
- KE (Yes/No)
- Status (Yes/No)
- Links (Yes/No)
- RootCause (Yes/No)
- Monitoring (Yes/No)

### Code

Below are the relative sections of my code (I haven't put it all in as there is a lot that is not relative):

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE CheckDate BETWEEN #" & strFrom & "# AND #" & strTo & "#"
Set rstQuestions = dbsQualityCheck.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If Not (rstQuestions.EOF And rstQuestions.BOF) Then
    rstQuestions.MoveFirst
    Do Until rstQuestions.EOF = True
        REST OF CODE
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "There are no checks against this Analyst"
End If
```

### Issue

The issue here is that I always end up with the Message Box advising that there are no checks against the analyst. I can only assume that the data is not correct or the date is not formatted correct on one side of the check but I am unable to see where the fault lies.

I have also tried the following as the strSQL string:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE CheckDate BETWEEN #29/11/2015# AND #01/12/2015#"
```

Comment: Have you tried, just 1 criteria, less than, it could be your dates are becoming US like 12/1/2015

Comment: Using 1 criteria does indeed seem to work!

Comment: try criteria  as Format(strFrom,"yyyy/mm/dd")

Comment: If you type that up as an answer, I'll accept it as it's working now.

Comment: ok added thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to format your criteria  as

```
SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE 
 CheckDate BETWEEN #" 
& format(strFrom,"yyyy/mm/dd") & 
"# AND #"
 & format(strTo,"yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"
```